# How to dynamically load jQuery in a javascript function, call another function, and return that function's return value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which uses jQuery. I need to dynamically inject jQuery with JavaScript and have that function return that function’s return value. I would like to do something like

```
(function(){
    var jQueryLoaded = false;
    var returnValue;
    if (!window.jQuery) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js';
        script.onreadystatechange= function () {
            if (this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')
                onJQueryLoaded();
        };
        script.onload = onJQueryLoaded;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }
    else {
        returnValue = myJQueryFunction();
        if (typeof(returnValue) == 'undefined')
            returnValue = true;
        return returnValue;
    }
    function myJQueryFunction() {
        // do something
    }
    function onJQueryLoaded() {
        if (jQueryLoaded)
            return;
        jQueryLoaded = true;
        var $ = jQuery;
        returnValue = myJQueryFunction();
        if (typeof(returnValue) == 'undefined')
            returnValue = true;
    }
    while (typeof(returnValue) == 'undefined'); // wait until onJQueryLoaded returns
    return returnValue;
})();
```

but `onJQueryLoaded` does not get called during the `while` loop.

Is there any way to have my base function wait until `onJQueryLoaded` gets called before returning?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up a timer/interval, and checking with that.  That'll do what you're looking for, as far as executing a callback which is dependent upon time (i.e. something loading, rendering, downloading, uploading).
Or just place it inside of jQuery itself.

Comment: Timer will just call another function; I need the original, base function to return `myJQueryFunction`’s return value (or true).

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass a function pointer into your myJQueryFunction().

You can then call that function within this method.

something like

```
function myJQueryFunction(funcPoint) {
        funcPoint();
    }

returnValue = myJQueryFunction(function() {return true;});
```

syntax might need a little more looking into as thats just off the top of my head.

**Edit**

Prob more relevant a scenario like this

```
var func = function() {return true;};

...stuff......

function myJQueryFunction(funcPoint) {
        funcPoint();
    }

returnValue = myJQueryFunction(func);
```

**More edit**

As per my comment below, if what you want is to fire a function once JQuery is loaded (ready) you want to use the JQuery ready function

```
$(document).ready(function() {do you stuff here});
```

[Jquery Ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: This does not answer the question: it just calls another function for a return value; I am asking how to wait until `myJQueryFunction` gets called.

Comment: you can't "wait" until a function gets called in the way your asking. Jquery/JavaScript isn't asycronous, it's not even compiled it's a scripting language and does not support concurency.

Comment: wait a mo...do you want to call a function after JQuery loads? If so you want $(document).ready(function() {....});

Answer (score 0):

surely you could solve this much simpler with something like ...

Load the jquery script ...

```
(function() {
    if (!window.jQuery) {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js';
        }
})();
```

use a jquery "onload" function from here ...

```
$(function() { console.log("jquery is now loaded"); });
```